# nginx proxy_pass to root without path

Tags: nginx

In the [nginx proxy_pass documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) it says

> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is **passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client** when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI

(emphasis mine)

What if I want to proxy `/foo` to `http://localhost:8080` without trailing `foo`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `http://localhost:8080/` with the trailing slash, denoting `/` as the URI. You cannot do this in named locations (AFAIK, nginx will throw error).